# Как включит Just-In-Time Debugger на Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: отладка, visual-studio-2017

Понадобилась Just-In-Time Debugger. В настройках его нет 
[image: Options]

Где то нашел такое решение 
[image: Настройки Internet]

Но оно не помогает. Каждый раз Visual Studio дает такую ошибку (Во время Rebuild)

[image: Ошибка]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправил через Visual Studio Installer. Просто добавил компонент:

[image: Visual Studio Installer]